# How to grant read and write permission for topics users created

Tags: apache-kafka

Right now, all users are able to create any topic they want. But the problem is they have no permission on for that topic. I want the topic creator to have the read and write permission on the topic they've created.

Comment: Have you looked how at [Kafka ACLs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html#acl-format)?

Comment: @artiomi yes but my requirement not mentioned int that doc